# Closed questions for tool/recommendation are showing the same but different messages! And the blue # not showing either

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, vote-to-close, custom-close-reasons

Questions that are closed as *"recommend or find a tool, library, or favorite off-site resource"* are doing 2 of the same ***but different*** close reason messages.

[image: evidence]

Here's some links to closed questions that reproduce this issue : [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24268243/learning-ninject-with-mvc-5-beginner) , [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23939854/matlab-getrect-alternative) , [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330526/calendar-heatmap-with-dc-js)

---

### Also, I think this other bug below may *possibly* be related.

[image: evidence2]

The blue 3 *(or blue however many votes)* works for other off-topic reasons, but has not been working for me for the *tool/recommendation* reason for like last 2 weeks. So maybe the reason it's not showing is because the 3 previous users are using the other recommendation/tool/library close reason? Is it possible that different users are receiving different close reasons to choose from even though they are practically the same?

<sub>Special thanks goes to [Unihedron](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3622940/unihedron) for noticing the first bug mentioned here and making us aware of it! This post really wouldn't of happened if it weren't for his keen observation skills! [chat message link](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2341346#2341346)</sub>

Comment: The close reason was edited at some point in the middle of the closure process for those questions. Obviously the system is treating them as two different close reasons.

Comment: I noticed before yesterday. Be careful using "first" "last" "all" "any" "always" "never" "none".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

At some point in time the close message was replaced by one with more concise wording and a link. You can see this in your screenshot, the two messages do not match.

For any post currently in the review queue with votes only for the old reason, the system cannot know that the new version is basically a variant of the old, so no highlighting is shown.

This is the result of a simple and minor limitation in the off-topic reasons subsystem; you'll find this applies to any no-longer-used off-topic reason.

There are currently [5 no-longer active off-topic reasons on Stack Overflow](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220605/deactivated-off-topic-reasons), each of which would give the same results when you come across posts with such votes in the queue; you can see the older 'external resource' reason there with id 8. Compare that with the [currently active reasons](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/216660/off-topic-reasons), and you'll see the new reason has id 14.

Comment: This specific close reason has been updated again recently. The new id is 16.

Comment: @cVplZ: yes, that was Robert, see the other answer on this question.

Answer (score 4):

I put the link back.  The blue has returned.

Comment: So everything that has pending close votes for OT reason ID 14 won't have the blue anymore now?

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's correct. It's 16 now. And Robert, thanks, for fixing the other blue problem.