# Close reason for tool recommendation lacks link

Tags: bug, close-reasons

The close reason text in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25796186/how-to-programmatically-change-internet-slang-to-readable-english lacks any links:

> "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it." – Bill the Lizard

[Closed questions for tool/recommendation are showing the same but different messages! And the blue # not showing either](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269713/closed-questions-for-tool-recommendation-are-showing-the-same-but-different-mess) mentions this, but the reason given there doesn't apply here, because the former question was only asked three hours ago:

> At some point in time the close message was replaced by one with more
>   concise wording and a link. You can see this in your screenshot, the
>   two messages do not match.
>
> For any post currently in the review queue with votes only for the old
>   reason, the system cannot know that the new version is basically a
>   variant of the old, so no highlighting is shown.
>
> This is the result of a simple and minor limitation in the off-topic
>   reasons subsystem; you'll find this applies to any **no-longer-used
>   off-topic reason**.

Comment: If you are going to quote someone, you should (A) make it more clear you are quoting them and (B) actually link to the post you are quoting, and (C) give them credit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 are you talking about me, or about Bill the Lizard? Both pieces of texts I quote are on the same page, if not the same post, as the links I supply.

Comment: I think when they created the new reason they probably copy-pasted the old one and didn't realize they missed the link. Changing these is incredibly annoying because we can't just *modify* an existing reason. We have to create a new one, deactivate the old one, and then activate the new one.

Comment: *smells a feature-request from @animuson*