# Strange Close Vote Quantification

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

As I spend more time in the close vote queue, I am starting to notice infrequent odd discrepancies in the number of close votes versus the number of votes indicated in the blue numerical count for each reason.

As an example:

[Segmentation Fault with Direct Memory Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311777/segmentation-fault-with-direct-memory-access)

shows (at the time of writing) 2 close votes. Clicking on "close" brings up the close dialog, also showing 2 "duplicate of..." entries. Clicking on "duplicate of..." indicates that the reason was selected 4 times.

Similarly, sometimes I see no indicator on (for example), "off-topic because... ", but when I click into it, I will see 1 or 2 entries in "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.".

Is this just a case of the caching not always being up to speed, or could it be a legitimate bug? I've hesitated to bring it up, in the past, due to the ephemeral nature of the state of close votes on a particular object.

Comment: Also, if you are checking this out, please do not vote to close until this question is resolved - I'm not sure what affects the state.

Comment: I answered the question here (with screenshots) before closing it.

Comment: I have noticed this a lot too, but didn't think anything of it

Comment: If you notice this with closing questions as off topic - tool/resource reason... it's because that reason has been updated twice in the last couple months, so the 2 old wordings of it can't be voted on anymore. See [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269713/closed-questions-for-tool-recommendation-are-showing-the-same-but-different-mess)

Comment: @lostsock Right on! All of my mysteries are being unraveled today.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is pretty obscure, so good catch! The number displayed everywhere *except* for the "Closing > Duplicate" dialog represents the number of close *votes*. At the time I write this, two people have voted to close that question, so the number 2 appears.

[image: close(2) duplicate of... 2]

The number shown on the "Closing > Duplicate" dialog represents the number of close-voters *or close flaggers* who've chosen the *specific* duplicate target listed. In the case of your example, two close voters *and an additional two close flaggers* have all selected the same target question, so the number 4 is displayed next to it.

[image: question title 4]

Why? **Because it's important that close *voters* are able to select as a dup-target a question suggested by a close *flagger*.** Any number of flaggers (and up to 4 voters) may have specified any number of possible targets for the duplicate closure, and they'll be listed on that dialog with a number to indicate how many times they've been chosen.

Now, in the most common cases there'll only be one question listed there, which everyone has chosen - so you'll see a number on it that simply reflects the combined total of all voters and flaggers.

Comment: Interesting. That makes sense. Am I correct in assuming that the same logic would go for flagging for other (non-duplicate) reasons without a close vote? This may even explain why sometimes I get items in the close vote queue that don't have any apparent entries...

Comment: As a side note, I thought I read somewhere that flagging with a close reason and voting to close were basically the exact same. I'm guessing that has something to do with rep caps, or something...

Comment: Well, depends on how you define it - they're stored in the same place in the database, with FlagTypeIds 13 and 14 respectively, so they're *pretty similar* from that perspective... Of course, close *votes* can actually cause a post to be closed, whereas no number of close *flags* will do so. And yeah, this is possible for other close reasons, although usually less obvious.

Comment: "This is pretty obscure" actually I guessed this was happening... maybe I'm good at guessing.

Comment: Why not change the color or something? Orange to indicate flags?

Comment: @bjb568 Because there are 2 separate numbers that matter. One number with color doesn't cut it, two numbers will be somewhat confusing.

Comment: @Xan What's your comment have to do with colors?

Comment: Why differentiate between flags and votes, @bjb?

Comment: Consistency. CVs are blue everywhere. When some number is blue and in the close dialog, confusion. Another option is only show number of CVs, but order by number of CVs plus flags.