# Close votes disappeared from close reasons dialog

Tags: bug, close-reasons, user-interface

When I see `possible duplicate of ...` in the comments, I would expect to see a count of duplicates in the close reasons box; but since a few days back, it is not visible.  Is there a problem?

Reviewing the close votes queue, it doesn't appear to happen every time, but already the second duplicate candidate I looked it displayed these symptoms.

> [image: Observe the "possible duplicate of"... comment, but no Close (1)]

The question has a "possible duplicate of"... comment, but no indication that there are actually close votes.

> [image: Still in the close dialog, no Close(1) on duplicates]

Still, in the close dialog, there is no number balloon with the number of close votes already cast.

> [image: Finally, when you click "Duplicate", you see that there is one]

Finally, if you click through to "Duplicate of..." you see that somebody already voted for this close reason -- there is a blue balloon with a number (1) to indicate that this duplicate was nominated by an earlier close voter.

Comment: Don't you need 3k to close vote? I just looked, the user with that comment has less than 3k, so I'm assuming the 1 in the last screenshot is for a _flag_, not a close vote.

Comment: Then why does the balloon show up on the final screen?  But I guess you could be right.

Comment: I'm trying to find where I've seen something talking about this before- I'm pretty sure it only shows up there to let you know how many people have _flagged_ or closed for that particular dupe.

Comment: [Found it!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271670/2607247) I knew I had seen this explained somewhere. :)

Comment: @Kendra I guess you should post that as an answer (or just mark this as duplicate ... ironically).

Comment: I honestly don't think I could possible explain it better than Shog. Glad I could help you find the answer, though. :)