# The same close reason two times

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I reviewed this question: [Best approach to compress Less files and JS files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094045/best-approach-to-compress-less-files-and-js-files)

And then this happened:

[image]

When I hit the close button (before the above screenshot) I saw 4 already cast close-votes:

> [image]

and when opening the off-topic reasons I saw only 1 (and no custom close reasons):

> [image]

How is this possible? What is going on?

Comment: spot the difference :D

Comment: @Shog9 Thanks, but it would mean that the first 3 votes were at least 2 months in the queue without aging away judging by the date of the linked duplicated question. This is kind of strange. Was there a second change?

Comment: They were in there since Aug 2nd, @ArtjomB. The second change coincides with Robert's answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269713/closed-questions-for-tool-recommendation-are-showing-the-same-but-different-mess/271275#271275